# Beginner questions about Wagtail (in comparison with Django)

Tags: django, wagtail

I'm a beginner learning Wagtail, and a lot of things are un-clear to me, and unfortunately not found sufficient explanation in Wagtail documentation.

Please help and give me some answers, and I feel I'm on the edge of giving up on Wagtail and switching back to Django.

Here are a few noob questions I have,

- How to handle POST request? 
  I've watched a few tutorials at [LearnWagtail.com](https://learnwagtail.com/tutorials/), it seems in Wagtail, development is all about creating models, no need to set urls.py or views.py.
  And we could create `Routable` pages to respond to custom url-patterns.

  **Question**: but how to respond to POST request if without defining a view? I don't see any example of `Routable` page handling POST request.
- Is the `home` app the only entry to a Wagtail website? 
  From what I see, `home` app is a default one created by Wagtail when a project is created. And the `home.HomePage` is the default page when I open the website on 127.0.0.1:8000.

  **Question**: so I cannot remove this `home` app?
- How to set `urls.py` or should we set them? 
  For example, a typicall `urls.py` settings are as follows. And my understanding is the `wagtail_urls` will point to `home.HomePage` by default.

  **Question**: so in Wagtail, we don't need to set any url patterns? Just to ensure subclass `Page` classes, all pages will be served by `wagtail_urls` by default?

```py
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^django-admin/', admin.site.urls),

    url(r'^admin/', include(wagtailadmin_urls)),
    url(r'^documents/', include(wagtaildocs_urls)),

    url(r'^search/$', search_views.search, name='search'),

]

urlpatterns = urlpatterns + [
    # For anything not caught by a more specific rule above, hand over to
    # Wagtail's page serving mechanism. This should be the last pattern in
    # the list:
    url(r"", include(wagtail_urls)),
]
```

- What is the point of parent page and child page? 
  In Wagtail, the parent and child pages are 2 concepts I feel hard to understand. For example, there are even 2 attributes (`parent_page_types`, `subpage_types`) we could set on each page type, [details in doc](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/reference/pages/model_reference.html?highlight=subchild_page#wagtail.core.models.Page.parent_page_types).

  **Question**: what do we need parent or child concepts for pages? Is this meant to be categories of pages?

Comment: Follow-up quesiton: if `home.HomePage` is the entry point of website, why the `HomePage.slug` is not shown when I open 127.0.0.1?

Comment: I found why we might need parent & child pages in Wagtail in this video tutorial, https://youtu.be/-nxrUgx6fj0

Comment: You write "giving up on Wagtail and switching back to Django". Please note that Wagtail is a Django app. By using Wagtail you use Django. It is perfectly fine to combine Django urls/views and Wagtail page routes.

Comment: @allcaps I started doubting why I should use wagtail now... Since as I move on, I found there are many things not well supported in Wagtail (compared to Django), for example today, I created a few Django models on admin, and I found there is no bulk-operations support for this, image that I have a Django model `class ABC`, and 100 objects created programatically, and now I need to remove them on admin, gosh, this is mission impossible to manually remove one by one.

Comment: But you have Django and you can add the Django admin too. And second, if you create objects programatically, why delete them by hand? You are the developer. `python manage.py shell` and delete them. Finally, bulk actions are on Wagtails wish list. But it is open source. Someone that really wants it needs to write it.

Comment: As a developer you choose packages because they bring features you need in your project. If you need CMS features (page tree, schedule publishing, workflow, document, image) then Wagtail might be for you. But if you do not need CMS features, why use it in the first place? You write "I found there are many things not well supported in Wagtail (compared to Django)" That ain't true. Again: Django is the framework, Wagtail is written op top of it. If you install Wagtail, you have Django too. So use both. Enable the Django admin if you need it. Uninstall Wagtail if you don't need a CMS.

Comment: @allcaps Thanks so much for you comments! Right, I'll try to use Django admin for some of the missing features.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hopefully the answers below help somewhat. I think it might be good for you to read a bit more deeply into the official [Wagtail documentation](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/). Learn Wagtail is an awesome resource, I have used some of their posts myself, but it will not cover everything you could possibly want to do with Wagtail.

Some good starting points on the Wagtail docs are:

- [Wagtail Tutorial](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/getting_started/tutorial.html)
- [The Zen of Wagtail](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/getting_started/the_zen_of_wagtail.html)
- [Pages Reference](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/reference/pages/index.html)

#### 1. How to handle POST request?

- You can do any kind of arbitrary handing of the serving of pages (including handling POST requests) by overriding the `serve` method on your page.
- Docs: https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/reference/pages/model_recipes.html#overriding-the-serve-method
- Note: if you want to do more complex route handling, where the page structure itself is not enough, you may find [`RoutablePageMixin`](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/reference/contrib/routablepage.html) useful. This is not really needed most of the time though.

#### 2. Is the home app the only entry to a Wagtail website?

- No, the location where you keep your `Page` models is 100% up to you, you can keep everything in one app, or keep a 'pages' app or whatever kind of structure makes sense for your project.
- Note: migrating models between apps may not be straight forward, so be careful and research if you are moving models between apps when they have existing data.
- Docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/applications/

#### 3. How to set urls.py or should we set them?

- You can set any urls you want in `urls.py`, however Wagtail should not need them for most scenarios.
- Wagtail generates the url routes based on your page structure and the `slug` on the `Page`.
- Docs: https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/reference/pages/model_reference.html#wagtail.core.models.Page.get_url
- Have a read of [Anatomy of a Wagtail Request](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/reference/pages/theory.html#anatomy-of-a-wagtail-request).

#### 4. What is the point of parent page and child page?

- Wagtail's pages follow a tree structure, the parent and child concepts are core to how Wagtail's URL routing and editing interface works.
- Have a read of [introduction to trees](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/reference/pages/theory.html#introduction-to-trees) for a bit of a high level overview.
- [`subpage_types`](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/reference/pages/model_reference.html#wagtail.core.models.Page.subpage_types) is a `Page` model attribute to allow you to control what pages can be created UNDER a page.
- [`parent_page_types`](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/reference/pages/model_reference.html#wagtail.core.models.Page.parent_page_types) is a `Page` model attribute to allow you to control what pages can be created ABOVE a page.
- The reason there are controls for each 'direction' is that this gives the developer full freedom to create structured hierarchies of pages. I personally find using `subpage_types` only in my projects helps keep things simple.
- If you want to dive deeper, you can read up on the [`django-treebeard`](https://django-treebeard.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library that underpins the tree structure that Wagtail uses.

#### 5. If home.HomePage is the entry point of website, why the HomePage.slug is the default URL

- This is intentional, otherwise what would be the 'entry' of your website.
- I can see how it can be confusing, but it makes sense for the 'root' of your site to go somewhere that you set up, this being your home page.

Comment: One follow-up question is, when to use Page model types, and when to use Django model types?

This doesn't make much sense, since for example, I'm building a blog website, typically have BlogListingPage and BlogDetailPage, both are wagtail Page models. But I can also define them as Django models, since I just need models to hold the blog detail data, page is all about html representation, so doesn't need to be wagtail page at all, right?

Comment: I would recommend a Page model for any model that will have a single URL (ie. a page). Remember that Page models are also just Django models also, so anything Django models can do Page models can do. Another way to think about it is anything that needs to be in the 'tree' should be a Page or anything that you want editors to access via the admin page editing interface should be a page.

Comment: Thanks for the your answer, I'll think more about your suggestions.